# Use COUNT inside a CONSTRUCT function in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, triplestore, topbraid-composer

I am trying to write a SPIN-Rule that will count the number of incoming references and set this number as a property value. E.g., count number of Issues that occurred on a particular machine. Therefore I need to count the number of incoming references of type `rdfs:occuredOn` (domain: Issue, range: Machine).

```
CONSTRUCT {
?machine rdfs:numberOfIssues ?n .
}

WHERE {
?machine a ex:Machine .
?issue a ex:Issue .
?issue ?r ?machine .
(COUNT(?r) AS ?n) //Error
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand why you use the rdfs and owl prefixes for your own entities.

Comment: I actually dont, thought it'll be easier to read..

Comment: I suggest changing the `rdfs:` and `owl:` prefixes in your example to `ex:`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only [`GroupGraphPattern`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rGroupGraphPattern) is allowed, i.e., you have to use a sub-`SELECT` query in the `WHERE` clause:

```
CONSTRUCT 
  { 
    ?machine rdfs:numberOfIssues ?n .
  }
WHERE
  { { SELECT  ?machine (COUNT(?r) AS ?n)
      WHERE
        { ?machine  a  owl:Machine .
          ?issue    a  owl:Issue ;
                    ?r        ?machine
        }
      GROUP BY ?machine
    }
  }
```

*Note, you should **never** user built-in namespaces/prefixes (such as `owl:`, `rdfs:`, `rdf:`, `xsd:`, etc.) for your domain ontology!*

Comment: thank you for the help and the advice!